# Transforming a list to a column vector in Python

Tags: python, numpy, transpose

I was wondering if there's a function that takes a list `X` as input and outputs a column vector corresponding to `X`?

(I looked around and I suspect it might be: `np.matrix(X).T` )

Comment: Are you using numpy?

Comment: Yes I am using numpy

Comment: `np.reshape(X, (len(X), 1))` - It'll also accept `X` even if it's a `list` or `tuple`

Comment: @drooze. -1 probably easier than len(X) here.

Comment: @Mkach. I've edited your tags to reflect that. This is a very common question so I'm glad you asked it. It's probably a duplicate but I'm too lazy to look so just posted an answer instead.

Comment: The basic point is that `np.array([1,2,3,4])`, makes a 1d array, shape `(4,)`.  Often that's enough.  A column vector has shape `(4,1)`.  There are lots of way of adding that dimension to the 1d array.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think there is a function, but there is a dedicated object, `np.c_`

```
>>> X = list('hello world')
>>> X
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
np.c_[X]
array([['h'],
       ['e'],
       ['l'],
       ['l'],
       ['o'],
       [' '],
       ['w'],
       ['o'],
       ['r'],
       ['l'],
       ['d']], dtype='<U1')
```

You can also do (note the extra square brackets)

```
>>> np.array([X]).T
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to convert a Python list into a numpy column vector, you can use the `ndmin` argument to the `array` conductor:

```
col_vec = np.array(X, ndmin=2)
```

Simply constructing an array will give you a 1D array, which can not be directly transposed:

```
a = np.array(X)
a is a.T
```

There are a couple of ways to transform a 1D vector into a column though:

```
col_vec = a.reshape(-1, 1)
```

and

```
col_vec = a[np.newaxis, :]
```

are fairly common idioms after your list is already an array.

```
col_vec = np.reshape(X, (-1, 1))
```

and

```
col_vec = np.expand_dims(X, -1)
```

will work even on a raw list.

P.S. Stay away from `np.matrix` it's very outdated and limited, if not outright deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

A list is a native type of Python, whereas a numpy array is a numpy object. You will need to convert your list to a numpy array first. You can do something like the following.

```
x = list(range(5))
print(x)
```

> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

```
x_vector = np.asarray(x)
```

> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

Now, Python does not know whats the difference between a row vector and a column vector, that is up to how you will use the vector. The current vector is 1x5. If you want 5x1, you can take the transpose by either

```
x_vector.T
```

or

```
np.transpose(x_vector)
```

However, since this is a 1D matrix, the transpose is the same as the non-transposed vector in memory.

Comment: As you guessed, transpose won't work correctly. You can't swap two dims when there aren't two dims to swap.

Answer (score 0):

similar but different:

```
mylist=[2,3,4,5,6]
```

**method1:**

```
np.array([[i] for i in mylist])
```

output:

```
array([[2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6]])
```

**method 2:**

```
np.array(mylist).reshape(len(mylist),1)

output:
    array([[2],
           [3],
           [4],
           [5],
           [6]])
```