# Converting list into Numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I want to convert this list

```
li = [3, 2 , 1 , 4]
```

to the following NumPy ndarray

```
[[3], [2], [1], [4]]
```

I tried with `np.asarray()` but it is not converting it into an `ndarray`. Is there any way to mention the axis?

Comment: What does `np.asarray()` produce it isn't a `ndarray`?  I expect it to produce a 1d array.

Comment: Same thing was asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49765578/transforming-a-list-to-a-column-vector-in-python

Comment: Could be argued to be more general, _"Is there any way to mention the axis?"_

Comment: Agree with @hpaulj, the same thing was asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49765578/transforming-a-list-to-a-column-vector-in-python.   There is a clean answer of using `np.reshape` in one of the comments of the question.

Answer (score 3):

`asarray` does produce a `ndarray`:

```
In [41]: li = [3, 2 , 1 , 4]
In [42]: x = np.asarray(li)
In [43]: x
Out[43]: array([3, 2, 1, 4])
In [44]: type(x)
Out[44]: numpy.ndarray
```

To produce the extra nesting, you need to add a dimension (in one way or other):

```
In [45]: np.asarray(li)[:,None]
Out[45]: 
array([[3],
       [2],
       [1],
       [4]])
```

Yesterday: [Transforming a list to a column vector in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49765578/transforming-a-list-to-a-column-vector-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) to create an array with an extra axis,

```
>>> np.expand_dims(li, -1)
array([[3],
       [2],
       [1],
       [4]])
```

or if you prefer, add the axis after array creation.

```
np.array(li)[..., np.newaxis]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create a nested list, then convert the nested list to a Numpy ndarray using [`numpy.array()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> li = [3, 2, 1, 4]

>>> np.array([[x] for x in li])    
[[3]
 [2]
 [1]
 [4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest is I believe

```
np.c_[li]
# array([[3],
#        [2],
#        [1],
#        [4]])
```

For general dimension and axis:

```
dummy, ndim, axis = 0, 4, 2
np.r_[f'{dummy},{ndim},{axis}', li]
# array([[[[3],
#          [2],
#          [1],
#          [4]]]])
_.shape
# (1, 1, 4, 1)
```

Another example:

```
dummy, ndim, axis = 0, 3, 0
np.r_[f'{dummy},{ndim},{axis}', li]
# array([[[3]],
#        [[2]],  
#        [[1]],
#        [[4]]])
_.shape
# (4, 1, 1)
```